# Unused Argument error R code

Tags: r, arguments

I have a Problem with the following code for a Sampling Importance Resampling Algorithm. It Returns

> log=True: unused Argument

for the declaration of Theta.

```
T = 1e5
theta <- runif(T,0,1, log=TRUE) 
log.p <- function(x) dbeta(x, 3000+711, 17000+2201-711)
log.s <-  function(x) dunif(x, 0, 1,)
w <- function(t) log.p(t) / log.s(t)
HA <- sum(w(theta)%*%theta)/T
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that log was a argument to runif?

Comment: Type `?runif` in R console and check the documentation. It does not have `log` argument. There are only three arguments `n`, `min`, and `max` for which the values are to passed.

Comment: Are you looking for `theta = log(runif(T, 0,1))`?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that there is no `log` argument for the `runif` function.  Inspecting the documentation for the `*unif` family of functions (e.g. running `?runif`) shows us this:

```
Usage:

     dunif(x, min = 0, max = 1, log = FALSE)
     punif(q, min = 0, max = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
     qunif(p, min = 0, max = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
     runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone more well versed in R correct me if I'm wrong, but from  [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Uniform.html)  it looks like runif() doesn't take a log argument. Just stop passing log=true, because it doesn't do anything here.

Comment: Downvote for suggesting that R functions should accept arbitrary arguments.

Comment: I edited it anyway, but wouldn't it make more sense for this to raise a warning and not an error because this causes unexpected, but not dangerous or undefined behavior

Comment: @HenryPrickett-Morgan On the contrary, it’s extremely dangerous because the function might add the parameter in a later version, with different behaviour. More fundamentally, there’s simply no reason to allow this behaviour: it’s always, unambiguously wrong. Why would R *not* forbid this? There’s ample evidence that strict error checking leads to better code quality.

Comment: It's safer to have an error thrown so that users get an unambiguous signal that they have done something the author was not prepared to support. In this instance the log function is designed for probabilities and there's really no sensible notion for small probabilities in a random number generator.